# What is this regex: /^\D(?=\w{5})(?=\d{2})/ is not matching "bana12"?

Tags: javascript, regex

The objective is to match strings that are greater than 5 characters long, do not begin with numbers, and have two consecutive digits. I thought my regex was enough to do that but is not matching "bana12".

This regex does the job:

```
var pwRegex =  /^\D(?=\w{5})(?=\w*\d{2})/;
```

Is not this regex more restrictive than mine? Why do I have to specify that the two or more digits are preceded by zero or more characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is less restrictive than yours.

After the `\D`, there are 2 lookaheads. For your regex, they are

```
(?=\w{5})(?=\d{2})
```

This means that the thing after the non-digit must satisfy both of them. That is,

- there must be 5 word characters immediately after the non-digit, *and*
- there must be 2 digits immediately after the non-digit.

There is `ana12` immediately after the non digit in the string. `an` is not 2 digits, so your regex does not match.

The working regex however has these two lookaheads:

```
(?=\w{5})(?=\w*\d{2})
```

It asserts that there must be these two things immediately after the `\D`:

- 5 word characters, *and*
- a bunch of word characters, followed by two digits

`ana12` fits both of those descriptions.

Try this [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j6wuQR/1). Look at step 6 in the regex debugger. That is when it tries to match the second lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track to maybe use lookaheads, and also with the correct start of your pattern, but it is missing a few things.  Consider this version:

```
^\D(?=.*\d{2})\w{4,}$
```

Here is an explanation of the pattern:

```
^                from the start of the string
    \D           match any non digit character
    (?=.*\d{2})  then lookahead and assert that two consecutive digits occur
    \w{4,}       finally match four or more word characters (total of 5 or more characters)
$                end of the string
```

The major piece missing from your current attempt is that it only matches one non digit character in the beginning.  You need to provide a pattern which can match 5 or more characters.